# How to make a QUiLoader as a modal dialog?

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, qdialog

> In my application I have several pop ups to be shown and each has
>   different UI layouts so it was difficult to code everything and during my 
>   search to make my coding life easier, I
>   stumbled upon `QUiLoader` and thought it would make it easier. But
>   here is the problem:
>
> I have created a `QDialog` class with a
>   `setDialogType()` API which loads a `.ui` file based on the type of dialog
>   I chose. So naturally, since this is a pop up I wanted it to be a
>   modal dialog and since `QUiLoader` returns a `QWidget*`, I can't downcast
>   it to `QDialog` and since I actually subclassed `QDialog` to show this
>   QUiloader , I tried setModal() on it but alas, the dialog itself
>   became
>   modal, meaning it does not receive the button events, for example.
>
> Can
>   anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: If `QWidget*` returned by `QUiLoader` is actually a `QDialog*`, you can downcast it using `dynamic_cast` or `qobject_cast`.

Comment: QUiloader returns QWidget* then, in that case, I can't downcast it...